# Glyphicon not showed with laravel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, glyphicons

I've included glyphicon icons in my Laravel webapp in this way:

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>`

but they are not shown because the resource is not found.

Below the details of the HTTP 404:

```
GET http://localhost:8000/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-
halflings-regular.woff2 [HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found 168ms]
downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings" 
style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:1): status=2147746065 
source: http://localhost:8000/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-
sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2?
448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does that error not explain what you need to do? They can't be found at the location they're being requested from...

Comment: the font loaded from ```http://localhost:8000/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2``` is not reachable to the server (404). Check if the path is correct

Comment: Folder _your_project/public/fonts_ is missing. 
I create a standard laravel project using composer. Should I do something else? 
Laravel version is 5.5.12.

Answer (score 2):

Check if there is **glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2** file under *your_project/public/fonts/vendor/bootstrap-sass/bootstrap*

The error is saying that your browser cannot find this file, maybe the path is wrong.

Comment: Folder _your_project/public/fonts_ is missing. 
I create a standard laravel project using composer. Should I do something else? 
Laravel version is 5.5.12.

Comment: Yes, you should include the fonts in your public folder, then change the path on your CSS file, so the browser will be able to fetch your fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use CDN for that in your html head.

```html
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-glyphicons.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Now try-

```html
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
```

Comment: this should be posted as a comment not as an answer.